# LINQ where not between a date range

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I have the following linq query:

```
public static int GetContributions(PERSON person, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {
        using (var db = new TestEntities())
        {
            var creditsSum = (from u in db.PERSON_SOCIAL_INSURANCE_CONTRIBUTIONS
                              where u.StartDate >= startDate
                              where u.EndDate <= endDate
                              where (u.PersonId == person.Id)
                              select (int?)u.NumOfContributions).Sum() ?? 0;

            return creditsSum;
        }
    }
```

I would like to create a similar method that returns the number of contributions that do not fall between the start and end date provided. So basically for it to return all entries that do not fall between startDate and endDate values.

Any help?

Comment: Can you explain the term `fall`? No intersection with given interval or full inclusion?

Comment: I mean No intersection with given interval

Answer (score 1):

AND all of your conditions together, put parentheses around them, and negate.

```
var creditsSum = (from u in db.PERSON_SOCIAL_INSURANCE_CONTRIBUTIONS
                          where !(u.StartDate >= startDate
                          && u.EndDate <= endDate)
                          where (u.PersonId == person.Id)
                          select (int?)u.NumOfContributions).Sum() ?? 0;
```

Comment: The intersection can arise.

Answer (score 0):

Change your conditions then:

```
var creditsSum = (from u in db.PERSON_SOCIAL_INSURANCE_CONTRIBUTIONS
                  where (u.StartDate > endDate || u.EndDate < startDate) &&
                        u.PersonId == person.Id
                  select (int?)u.NumOfContributions).Sum() ?? 0;
```

You don't need that many where statements, just use AND operator.

Comment: If I make decision that the `u.StartDate < u.EndDate` and  `startDate < endDate` (which pretty much to be true), your `where` clause is `false`.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan You are right, updated the condition.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Where` clause can looks like this:

```
b.PERSON_SOCIAL_INSURANCE_CONTRIBUTIONS
 .Where(
           (c => c.StartDate > endDate || c.EndDate < startDate)
           && u.PersonId == person.Id
       )
```